# Dissimilarity with earlier features part of cost function

Tags: r, random-forest, loss-functions, ensemble-learning

I am using a RandomForest on features (pixels) of images, and I am considering adding cost for "similarity to already other included features" to the cost function.

Imagine you have a current RF model, which is using 400 features. Consider adding another 400 features. Since it becomes again tricky to figure out how to optimize a RF for 800 features, I was considering the following. The idea is that it would only make sense to add these 400 if the features perform well on the RF. However, that is not all. *What about "dissimilarity to already used features"?*

Would it make sense to add the dissimilarity to the predictions from the model with the earlier 400 features, and somehow subtract this from the cost? The idea here is that if the second model would do reasonable, though it is very different from the first model, then I suppose this might be very great to use in a final model including all features (better than a model with 400 features which basically explain the same variance, and thus combining them wouldn't lead to any improvement).

**Has dissimilarity with earlier model ever been considered in the cost function, and what would be a good formula (e.g. in terms of RMSE)?**

```
Example, where Z is old predicted values from first 400 variables and
       , where X are new predicted values from second 400 variables and
       , where Y is the ground truth. 

Old model:
RMSE(Z, Y) = 0.15

New model:
RMSE(X, Y) = 0.16

Consider:
if RMSE(X, Z) is high --> a lot of difference, so include variables
if RMSE(X, Z) is small --> the variables capture same information (redundant)
```

Wouldn't it be great that when we use cross validation to come up with a good model, that this "similarity with earlier features" is penalized?

Any thoughts/comments would be welcome.